# Strange behavior of App bar in windows 8 application

Tags: windows-8, winrt-xaml

I want to open an app bar when an item is selected in the from a listview and things are working as expected by using a boolean parameter and binding that to AppBar.IsSticky and AppBar.IsOpen.

The challenge which I am facing is once i open app bar normally (i.e. by right click or through touch sensor) the above functionality no longer works for me even though the binded boolean values with AppBar.IsSticky and AppBar.IsOpen is still getting true when a item from lisview is selected.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer, i was missing two way binding for AppBar.IsSticky and AppBar.IsOpen